# NSDateFormatter in singleton class or one for each section for less expensive code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, nsdateformatter

I've seen on a few threads, users creating categories to share a static instance of `NSDateFormatter`.

My app has multiple sections and a `singleton` class, each section have multiple views and some views do use `NSDateFormatter`. I use my `singleton` for sharing data between sections without having to repeat network connections.

I'm a little worried about the cost of `formatters`, and to deal with this issue I could create a method on my `singleton` class and `alloc`, `init` a `formatter`there, and it would be around the entire time, I could use a `category` or I could create one on the main view of each section, so at least I wouldn't need one for each view.

I guess the method on my `singleton` would go like this, right?

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *)sharedDateFormatter
{
    static NSDateFormatter *sharedDateFormatter = nil ;
    if (sharedDateFormatter == nil)
    {
        sharedDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
        [sharedDateFormatter setLocale: [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en_GB"] autorelease]] ;
        [sharedDateFormatter setDateFormat: @"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"] ;
    }
    return sharedDateFormatter ;
}
```

My question is, what is the best practice to reduce the cost of `NSDateFormatters`?

Comment: It depends on what you're doing.  It's relatively expensive to keep changing the date format, so sometimes you want several, one per format.  Other times it's simplest to just create the formatter when you need it, rather than worry whether it's set right or is in use by another thread or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A singleton is fine, but I'd use the dispatch_once pattern.

Problem: NSDateFormatter is not thread safe. If you use that same NSDateFormatter only on the same thread, or for example in the same serial dispatch queue, it's fine. Otherwise you have to either make the code thread safe, or use multiple NSDateFormatters, one per thread.

Comment: NSDateFormatter has been updated in iOS 7 to be thread safe. Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html